# Android post method after login in website

Tags: android, post, authentication

I'm trying to develop an APP for my family's restaurant in which the customer is able to make online purchases. We have a website which offers that possibily, so what i want to do is create an APP that simulates the website POST methods.

I'm able to login successfully to the website but after that POST methods don't work. How could i do this in Android? Maybe something related with cookies?

I'm using this methods:

public String PostInternetData(String tel, String pass) throws Exception{

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pedidos.pizzeriabritannia.com/index.asp?Opc=Pedir");
    StringBuilder data = null;
    String answer ="";
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", tel));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        data = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        answer = data.toString();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return answer;

}
```

Comment: Why doesnt it work? What error are you getting when you try to hit the request?

Comment: It seems to stay in the same page, before the login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be problem with ur cookie ,   Every time your creating a new `new DefaultHttpClient();`

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

so your login will have a cookie and it will change in new request , at `HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();`

use lib file httpmine-4.0.1.jar and apache-mine4j-0.6.jar

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmime401jar.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachemime4j06jar.htm
```

create a class

```
 public class HttpClientSingalTon {

private static Object yourLock = new Object();
private static CookieStore yourCookie = null;

public static HttpClient getHttpClienttest() {
    final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    synchronized (yourLock) {
        if (yourCookie == null) {
            yourCookie = httpClient.getCookieStore();
        } else {
            httpClient.setCookieStore(yourCookie);
        }
    }
    return httpClient;
}
```

}

and in your httppost() use

```
  HttpClient httpclient ;
    httpclient = HttpClientSingalTon.getHttpClienttest();
    HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
```

all your request should created by

```
   httpclient = HttpClientSingalTon.getHttpClienttest();
```

it will be cookie  for all the requests..
Hope it will slove your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to perform JSON requests to the server and use the results in your android app. Basically you post a request to a page on your web server which contains the database query, and have the server send the results back.

See here for a great set of examples :-) http://localtone.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html